# Dos section, uno a continuación del otro, el inferior con height del 100% que le queda

Tags: bootstrap, carrusel, height

Utilizando Bootstrap tengo dos **section**, uno a continuación del otro, en el **section** inferior tengo un **carousel** que muestra textos que tienen un título y un contenido, la consulta es cómo hago para que el **section** de la parte inferior ocupe el 100% de lo que necesite hasta el final de la pantalla para mostrar los textos del **carousel**, o sea, debería tener un **height** suficiente de acuerdo al texto más largo que muestra el **carousel**. Actualmente los textos se "salen" del **section**  porque éste no es lo suficientemente alto. Espero haberme explicado.
Dejo a continuación el código html de ejemplo y luego del css utilizado. El archivo de imagen **uno-background.png** cargado para el **background** de la **section-uno** es una imagen de 1920 x 1080. Muchas gracias.

Código del html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

    <head>
        <!-- META TAGS -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
            content="ie=edge">

        <!-- LINK A ARCHIVOS CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="estilos.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>PRUEBA</title>

    </head>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>
        PRUEBA
    </title>

    <body>

        <section class="section-uno text-center">
            <h1>SECCIÓN UNO</h1>
        </section>

        <section class="section-dos text-white">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="carouselExampleControls"
                    class="carousel slide"
                    data-ride="carousel">

                    <div class="corousel-inner">

                        <div class="carousel-item active">

                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur nemo maiores, saepe corporis, repudiandae accusamus ex quas commodi blanditiis expedita atque perspiciatis error totam tempore ipsa modi quasi voluptatum nesciunt aut! Voluptatem eum excepturi itaque nemo accusantium quam fugiat aliquid autem deserunt at! Velit vel laborum quae laboriosam quod error?</p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">

                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia excepturi debitis esse vero? Eaque quasi suscipit amet reiciendis modi ducimus delectus ipsam, corporis at commodi numquam explicabo velit, saepe laudantium.</p>

                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">

                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae consequuntur voluptatibus atque laborum explicabo delectus inventore mollitia repellat corrupti nesciunt.</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev"
                    href="#carouselExampleControls"
                    role="button"
                    data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"
                            aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next"
                    href="#carouselExampleControls"
                    role="button"
                    data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"
                            aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        
    </body>

</html>
```

El código del archivo **estilos.css** es el siguiente:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.section-uno {
    padding: 200px 0px;
    background: url(uno-background.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#carouselExampleControls > .corousel-inner {
    padding: 0px 120px;
}

.section-dos {
    padding: 100px 0px;
    background: #180870;
}
```